# PHP - While loop form.

Tags: php

I have this while loop, which echos out a form onto a page.

So this page is essentially filled with all rows from the DB, (sort of like a news feed with posts)

I have a button at the end of the form, which lets users reply to this post.

How do I set the variables, to take the values from whichever post they click apply on, and take them to a new PHP document which is the application page where users can fill in another form.

```
while($value= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

echo '<div class="form">';
echo"<div class='field-warp'>".$value['brand_uid']."</div>";
echo"<div class='field-warp'>".$value['value1']."</div>";
echo"<div class='description'>".$value['value2']."</div><br>";
echo"<div class='field-warp'>".$value['value3']."</div><br>";
echo"<button class='button button-block' name='apply' />Apply to 
collaborate</button>";
echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your feed database table probably has an id column or some other unique identifier.

So have the button be a link or turn it to a link and style it as a button. Currently your button could look like this:

```
echo '<button class="button button-block" name="apply" onclick="location.href=\'http://your_domain.com/feed_apply.php?id='.$row["feed_id"].'\';" />Apply to collaborate</button>';
```

Then in your feed_apply.php you can fetch that id like so:

```
$feed_id = $_GET['id'];
$feed_data = [];
// query your database to set $feed_data
```

Now you can pre-populate or use data elsewhere in your application form.

Answer (score 0):

Why not replace the button with an a href link with a GET parameter with the post ID, then on the processing page you retrieve the post ID and its information with your new form?